# C# bank system SortedSet

Tags: c#, class, oop, sortedset, bank

I tried to make a bank system that save the accounts in a sorted set by there balance (on desnding order).

when i printing the accounts its (using the for each in the main) dose not print in desanding order, its printing in inseration oreder (a1 a2 a3....) way?

allso, is it ok to add a instance to tha sorted set in the consractur? is there better way to that?

```
class Bank : IComparable<Bank>
{
    private static int numOfAccounts = 0;
    private readonly int _id;
    private double _balance;
    private static SortedSet<Bank> _banks { get; } = 
        new SortedSet<Bank>(new BankComperatorByBalance() );

    public Bank()
    {
        _id = numOfAccounts;
        numOfAccounts++;
        _banks.Add(this);
    }

    
    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is Bank other))
        {
            return false;
        }
      
        return this._id == other._id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
    public Bank(double balance) : this()
    {
        this._balance = balance;
    }

    public void deposit(double balance)
    {
        _banks.Remove(this);
        this._balance += balance;
        _banks.Add(this);
    }
    public bool withdrawal(double balance)
    {
        if(this._balance>= balance) { 
            this._balance -= balance;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public bool transfer(Bank reciver,double balance)
    {
        if (this._balance - balance >= 0)
        {
            this.deposit(balance);
            reciver.deposit(balance);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        return "id: " + this._id + "\nBalance: " + this._balance;
    }

    public static SortedSet<Bank> GetBanks()
    {
        return _banks; 
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var b in GetBanks().Reverse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.toString());
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Bank? other)
    {
       if(other == null) return -1;
       if(other._balance == this._balance) return _id.CompareTo(other._id);
       return _balance.CompareTo(other._balance);
    }
}

class BankComperatorByBalance : Comparer<Bank>
{
    public override int Compare(Bank? x, Bank? y)
    {
        if(x == null) return 1;
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe fix the obvious bugs, first. For example depositing in both accounts on transfer or inserting to the SortedSet on deposit, only. And of course using `double` type for money.

Comment: I would recommend. 1) Remove all the statics from the code, except main, 2) rename `Bank` to `Account`, if that is what it actually represents. 3) Implement a separate `IComparer`, so you can order your accounts in multiple ways. 4) Use a Dictionary to store your accounts, with the Id as key. 5) Order the accounts where you display them. 6) forget any concerns about performance, you should always focus on readability and correctness first, but it is even more important for simple exercises like this.

Comment: thanks for the response. way should not i use static here? how could i give an id to each instance and sotre it?

Comment: I'd also suggest that a bank account doesn't have a `Balance` property with a backing field. You should compute the balance based on the current transactions in the account. Otherwise you can have a situation where the balance and the transactions don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i understand u want to print items in descending order, then you need to change your GetBanks() method from this:

```
public static SortedSet<Bank> GetBanks()
{
    return _banks; 
}
```

to this:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Bank> GetBanks()
{
    // here we ordering banks by balance:
    return _banks.OrderByDescending(b => b._balance);
}
```

and finally call like this:

```
foreach (var b in GetBanks())
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.toString());
}
```